# show facebook profile pic in angular 5

Tags: angular, facebook, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on angular 5 and firestore. The profile pic and facebook profile pic url are store in firestore collection and i am retrieving them as:

```
      <tr *ngFor="let user of users | async >

         <td>
            <div class="avatar" >
              <img src="{{user.photoUrl}}" style="width:100%; height:100%" >
            </div>
```

all pictures are showing perfectly, however facebook profile pics are not showing anymore. Profile pic of facebook are store in firestore as:

http://graph.facebook.com/IcjfUJmPBgMbuZc5jCJcvfprP9f1/picture?type=large

How can i show facebook profile pic in my angular app? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: that is a weird ID for a facebook profile...are you sure that it ever worked? either way, it may be related to the recent breaking changes.

Comment: other url images are shown perfectly but not the facebook profile pictures are shown. Pictures which are loaded from google and facebook in firestore are not showing but the pictures which select user to update profile pic from gallery images are showing perfectly.